# Regex to capture first substring with the following properties

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a regex to capture the first substring with the following properties:

1. The substring contains no lowercase letters or symbols
2. The substring is **immediately** preceded by "..."
3. The substring is **immdiately** followed by "...\n

For example,  I'd like to capture "FOO BAR" in the following

"...this is TEXT...\n that...\nI DON'T CARE ABOUT...\nbut I do care about...FOO BAR...\nNothing else matters."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
// This will target only capitol letters and numbers and spaces
// it will also capture the first occurrence only
/\.\.\.[A-Z0-9 ]+\.\.\.\n/
```

**Here is an example usage:**

```js
var string = "...this is TEXT...\n that...\nI DON'T CARE ABOUT...\nbut I do care about...FOO BAR...\nNothing else matters.";

var regex = new RegExp(/\.\.\.[A-Z0-9 ]+\.\.\.\n/);
var res = regex.exec(string);
var result = res[0].substring(3, res[0].length - 4);  // strip out the ... and \n

console.log(result);
```